# Boolean_conversions Using reinterpret_cast<>

Tags: c++

Can any one Give the example for

```
 Boolean_conversions Using  reinterpret_cast<>
```

Iam getting the execution failure..Any one explain ..

Ex:

```
   void Boolean_Conversions()
     {
         bool b = 0;
         int *i = reinterpret_cast<int*> (&b);
  // iam expecting as *i is 0/false    ,but it is showing runtime error          
     }
```

Edit:
In ISO Standard
Section $5.2.10, para 1:

```
      "The result of the expression reinterpret_cast<T>(v) is the
  result of converting the expression v to type T. If T is a
  reference type, the result is an lvalue; otherwise, the re
  sult is an rvalue and the l-value to r-value (4.1), array
  to pointer (4.2), and function to pointer (4.3) standard c
  onversions are performed on the the expression v. Types sh
  all not be defined in a reinterpret_cast."
```

From this Iam trying ..I did many conversions ..like Array_to_Pointer,Function_To_Pointer,Integral/Pointer_Conversions ,etc...But i don't know why it is failing For Boolean Conversions.

Can any one tell why it is failing ..Otherwise Tell the Boolean COnversions using  reinterpret_cast.

Mostly It is Giving Run time failure in G++.CC/EDG/COdepad..etc compilers

Please Explain

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Reinterpret casts are nests full of undefined behaviors.

Comment: This cast makes absolutely no sense! Where did you read about this? There is already an implicit conversion between them, i.e all you need to do is `int i = b;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the output is not defined. Note that the conversion is undefined.

On my machine *i = 0xcccccc00

> Note the lsb which is 00

which corresponds to the value of the bool variable initialized with 0(false). The byte pattern in the other three bytes (assuming the size of int as 32-bits) is completely unspecified and depends on what is there in that memory/endianness etc.

Technically, however that is an undefined behavior because we are deferencing a memory location (all of) which we did not reserve/allocate.

Comment: In release mode this would crash.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: That's what UB means!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You've still not made it clear what you are trying to do! Are you aware for example that there are three casts:

```
TO_TYPE DEST_VAL = static_cast<TO_TYPE>(SOME_VAL);

TO_TYPE DEST_VAL = dynamic_cast<TO_TYPE>(SOME_VAL);
```

and the one you're hung up on:

```
TO_TYPE DEST_VAL = reinterpret_cast<TO_TYPE>(SOME_VAL);
```

Of these three, the last is the **most dangerous**, basically you are ignoring all the things the compiler is telling you about types and forcing your way on it! It implies that you know what you are doing, and in most cases, you don't.

Typically you should only use the last one as a LAST RESORT when the other two casts can't do what you need and you've carefully looked at the design, and consulted soothsayers etc.! It is NOT type safe, and IT MAKES NO GUARANTEES that the resulting object is what you expect it to be, as in what you are trying to do above.. `bool` and `int` may or may not have the same aligned storage and pointing to the address of a `bool` with a pointer that **should** point to an `int` and dereferencing could lead to potentially accessing all sorts of nether regions of memory...

Answer (score 0):

```
bool b = 0;
int *i = reinterpret_cast<int*> (&b);
```

this will store the memory address of `b` to `i` after it is "converted" to a suitable style for an `int` pointer. if you want you cast a `bool` to `int` just do

```
int i = reinterpret_cast<int> (b);
```

if `b` is `false`, yes indeed it will be `0`, otherwise it will be `1`.
You dont need `reinterpret_cast<int>` though. Read the other comments made on the thread and it will become clear.

Comment: Actually, `int i = reinterpret_cast<int>(b)` is undefined behaviour, and will likely not do what you expect because 1) the sizes may differ and 2) you don't know how are truth values represented in memory. If `b` is true you may get i = -1, i = 255, i = 65535, i = 1, i = random value ending with a 1, etc. If `b` is false, similarly.

Comment: I dont know about reinterpret cast much, but 1) I thought a bool was 1 byte long and an int at least 16 (according to stroustrup c++) 2) I thought truth values are 0==false, everything_else==true. the values you refer to are problems arising from the reinterpret_cast ?

Comment: @Alexandre C - More likely "implementation-defined" than "undefined" (though if you're trying to write portable code there's little difference). See http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/glossary.html

Comment: My compiler is telling me that this is an invalid cast (an error). A correct thing to do in this situation is: `int i = b;` or use a `static_cast` or a C-style cast, or a function-style cast.

Comment: @Muggen: `reinterpret_cast` is a "blind" cast: it doesn't try to convert anything. If for your implementation `true == 0xFF` and you reinterpret cast to an int, depending on endianness you'll likely get (assuming 32 bit int) `0xGGGGGGFF` or `0xFFGGGGGG` where G = garbage.

Comment: @Daniel: I think that reinterpret_casting anything except pointers is UB, not IDB.

Comment: @Alexandre C. No, it's just a compile error. Muggen's example above won't compile. I meant the representations in memory (for some types) are implementation-defined rather than undefined.